# Проблема с кодировкой в Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Есть Java код:

```
public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Привет, мир!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Скрипт groovy, для запуска (есть кодировка UTF-8):

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'ru.kazbo.gradletest.App'
}
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF8'
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Однако, всё равно получаю кракозябры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась ручной установкой кодировки в консоль:

```
chcp 1251
```